# How to define a __str__ method for a class?

Tags: python

In Python, the `object` class serves as the root superclass for all the (new-style) classes.  By default at least, applying `str` and `repr` to the "class instance" of any subclass of `object` produces the same result:

```
>>> class spam(object): pass
... 
>>> str(spam)
"<class '__main__.spam'>"
>>> str(spam) == repr(spam)
```

I would like to define a subclass of `object`, say `fancyobject`, that is identical to `object` in every way, except that applying `str` and `repr` to `fancyobject` itself produces different outputs:

```
>>> class ham(fancyobject): pass
...
>>> str(ham)
'ham'
>>> repr(ham)
"<class '__main__.ham'>"
```

Is there a way to do this in Python?

PS: I'm aware of the `__str__` special method, but it is my understanding that if class `A` overrides `__str__`, then the overriding method is called only when `str` is called on instances of `A`, not when it is called on `A` itself.  I.e.:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'from new __str__: ' + object.__str__(self)
... 
>>> str(A())
'from new __str__: <__main__.A object at 0x7f79c62a5310>'
>>> str(A)
"<class '__main__.A'>"
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Actually the same mechanism as for object instances applies for types.  Types are just objects themselves, so they are converted to strings by calling the `__str__()` method on *their* type, which is called the "metaclass".  So you have to overwrite the `__str__()` method on the metaclass:

```
class fancytype(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name__
class ham(object):
    __metaclass__ = fancytype
print ham
```

prints

```
ham
```

Comment: Anyone got a pointer to how Python 3.3 and later (are supposed to) have changed that?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard At the time I wrote this (which was before the release of Python 3.3), the then current development version of Python had changed the result of `str(some_type)` to simply `some_type.__name__`.  Apparently, this change never made it into the release, and I can't find any reference to it at the moment.  I'll remove the comment from the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set the default metaclass for a whole module like this

```
class fancytype(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name__

__metaclass__ = fancytype

class ham:
    pass
print ham
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but it looks to me like it applies only to "classic" classes.  I don't see how such technique could affect new-style classes (which inherit, directly or indirectly) from `object`.

Comment: @kjo: Well, the class `ham` in this example will automatically become a new-style class, because `fancytype` derives from `type`, which is the type of new-style classes.  Everything that derives from `ham` will be a `fancytype` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know; until now I had thought that the only way to define a new-style classes was to explicitly include `object`, or some subclass of it, in the `(...)` clause of the `class ham(...):` statement.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the new answer for Python 3. Basically, you pass in a metaclass as a keyword parameter to the class definition.

```
class fancytype(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name__
class ham(metaclass=fancytype):
    pass
print(ham)
```

prints

```
ham
```