# Python: __str__, but for a class, not an instance?

Tags: python, string, class

I understand the following Python code:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "An instance of the class A"
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> print a
An instance of the class A
```

Now, I would like to change the output of

```
>>> print A
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Which function do I need to overload to be able to do that? The solution has to work even if the class is never instantiated. Is the situation different in Python 2.x and 3?

Comment: Have you [checked](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+%2Bclass+%2Bstr&submit=search) for existing answers before asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a __str__ method for a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class)

Comment: I tried, but actually didn't find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define `__str__()` on the metaclass:

```py
class A(object):
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __str__(self):
            return "plonk"
```

Now, `print A` will print `plonk`.

**Edit**: As noted by jsbueno in the comments, in Python 3.x you would need to do the following:

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return "plonk"
class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

Even in Python 2.x it might be a better idea to define the metaclass outside the class body -- I chose the nested form above to save some typing.

Comment: As the O.P. asks about Python 3 compatibility, it should benoted that Python 3 does not support this form of assigning a metaclass, since the "metaclass" is passed as if it where a keyword parameter at class declaration. (so, the metaclass have to be defined before the class body)

Comment: @jsbueno: Thanks, missed that question.

Comment: Have you [checked](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+%2Bclass+%2Bstr&submit=search) for duplicates before answering?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I don't think I have to do a comprehensive search before *answering*.  I do so before *asking* a question, but if it takes me less time to answer than to search for duplicates, I simply answer.

Comment: Don't you think directing a person who asked to the already existing answer is better than duplicating site's content?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: To the person who asked, often a tailored answer is more useful.  In this case, the question you linked to doesn't contain information on how to use metaclasses in Python 3.  (I often tag questions as duplicates as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Define the `__repr__` method on your meta class:

```
class MetaClass(type):

    def __repr__(self):
          return "Customized string"

class TestClass(object):
   __metaclass__  = MetaClass


print TestClass # Customized string
```