# Convert object to string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

How to white toString function, or better make Python stringify object? Here the simple class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = float(x)
        self.Y = float(y)
```

Next code

```
print Point(1.1,22)
```

Gives

```
<__main__.Point object at 0x0000000002E7A588>
```

I expect to achieve something like outputs standard object `(time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=2, tm_min=52, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=191, tm_isdst=-1),)` or `Point(x=1.1,y=22)`

What is proper function name? Should I write it by myself?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class

Comment: You need to implement  `__str__` that displays your object how you want when you print it

Comment: What they said. You need to give your class a `__str__` and / or a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691101/what-is-the-purpose-of-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912852/how-do-i-change-the-string-representation-of-a-python-class

Comment: Another useful page on this topic is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print FWIW, for this case, I'd make `__repr__` return something like `"Point(x=1.1, y=22)"` and `__str__` return `"(1.1, 22)"`