# How can i add my objects into a list to choose them randomly to blit onto the screen?

Tags: python

When i try to put my objects into a list, i can not get an output with object names, it gives a weird output like "_ *main* _.object at 0x029E7210". I want to select my objects randomly to blit ONE of them onto the screen. But i could not figure this out.

```
car_main = pygame.image.load("car_main.png")
car_red_ = pygame.image.load("car_red.png")
car_blue = pygame.image.load("car_blue.png")

class cars:

    def __init__(self,x,y,car_type,w=50,h=100,s=5):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.s = s
        self.car_type = car_type

    def draw(self):
        dp.blit(self.car_type,(self.x,self.y))

car1 = cars(x,y,car_main)
car2 = cars(x,y,car_red)
car3 = cars(x,y,car_blue)
car_list = [car1,car2,car3]
rc = random.choice(car_list)
print(rc)

# output>  __main__.object at 0x02A97230
```

When I change

```
car_list = [car1,car2,car3] with;
car_list = [car1.car_type,car2.car_type,car3.car_type]

# output > Surface(50x100x32 SW)
```

But I want to see an output as my object names. Not as a string type ("car_main"). I want to get an output as the object name (car_main) directly.  Because in the main loop, i will choose one of them to blit onto the screen everytime when the loop renews itself.

Comment: It's printing an object's address in memory if you didn't define `__str__` method for it.

Comment: what kind of a code do i need?

Comment: You need a `__str__` for desired class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144026/how-to-define-a-str-method-for-a-class

Comment: Also you need to find the variable name in `globals()` or `locals()` - depends on your scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `__str__` for your class `Car` to let it properly handle object to string:

```
class Car:

    def __str__(self):
        for k, var in globals().items():
            if var == self:
                return k
        # default
        return "Car"
```

---

**Note1:** Usually use uppercased `Car` for a class and `car` for an instance.

---

**Note2:** Look up variable strings in `globals` is not reliable. You may not want to make all variables global, and manually search them in scope is tedious. Actually why don't you give your `Car` a `name` attribute? Then you nicely have:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

car = Car(name='first car')
print(car) # 'first car'
```

---

More read about "magic methods": https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#representations

Comment: i just added "name" into the __init__ method. and i called my object (car1 = cars("car_red",x,y,car_type) and it gives the name. should i  add __str__ ? because it seems like it works currently

Comment: @ArdaAltun Well, not 100% sure with your current code, but you should solve the perplex after reading the referenced link. It explains why/when you should define `__str__()`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `__str()__` magic method to your car class like so:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'car with x of {self.x}, y of {self.y}, and type of {self.car_type}'
```

Comment: It should not be a `print`!

Comment: Silly mistake! My bad. Edited to `return`

Comment: And OP actually wanted to print the variable string instead of inspecting :) while that's not a good idea.

Comment: how can i call this function? what should i type? when i type print(car.__str__) it gives a weird output

Comment: you can do that but once you've defined a str function you can just print car. If you don't like the output change the return